# Pass a string from an aspect to the JointPoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I have an aspect that executes for each methods in all the `Controller` classes. My aspect generates a `UUID` and i wanted to get this ID in my controller, so that i pass it to my service-layer and further process. I am not sure how to pass the `UUID` from an aspect to the `Controller`

Below is the aspect

```java
@Configuration
@Aspect
public class ApplicationAspect {



    @Before("execution(* com.spike.aop.arun.*Controller.*(..))")
    public void aspectForAllControllers() {
        System.out.println("Correlation ID generated");
        var correlationId = generateCorrelationId(); // need to pass this to controller

    }

    private String generateCorrelationId() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you create header object, put this new uuid value in header and in Controller receive it as normal value

Comment: This is a spring boot API

Comment: I suggested in context of spring boot only :facepalm:

Comment: Try this : `@Aspect("percflow(execution(* com.spike.aop.arun.*Controller.*(..)))")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is using `RequestContextHolder` and set the generated `UUID` as a request attribute.

Following code demonstrates the same

```
@Before("execution(* com.spike.aop.arun.*Controller.*(..))")
public void aspectForAllControllers() {
    System.out.println("Correlation ID generated");
    String correlationId = generateCorrelationId(); 
    RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes().setAttribute("UUID", correlationId, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);

}
```

and access the request attribute in the controller.

```
@GetMapping("/testUUID")
public void testUUID(HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("From Controller :"+request.getAttribute("UUID"));
}
```

or

```
RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes().getAttribute("UUID",RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
```

Comment: Lovely.. it worked exactly the way i wanted to.. Thank you very much